# Как обращаться к элементам списка структуры?

Tags: c, список

Есть такие 2 структуры:

```
struct door {
    int id;
    int status;
};

struct node {
    struct door *door_Info;
    struct node *Next;
};

struct node* init(struct door* door) {
    struct node *NewNode;
    NewNode -> door_Info = door;
    NewNode -> Next = NULL;
    return(NewNode);
};
```

И в мейне следующее:

```
int main() {
    struct door doors[DOORS_COUNT];
    struct node *forDoor;
    forDoor = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        forDoor -> door_Info -> id = 1;
        forDoor = forDoor -> Next;
        }
    }
 }
```

Не знаю,  как правильно обращаться к элементам структуры через список. `forDoor -> door_Info -> id = 1;` То есть как нужно записывать вот эту строку.

Comment: Кроме просто обращаться, нужно еще, чтоб было к чему обращаться...

Comment: Сложна. И как сделать, чтоб было к чему обращаться. Вон я пытаюсь внести туда элемент, но шот не знаю как правильно это сделать.

Comment: После выделения памяти нужно для этой структуры вызвать конструктор или вручную выставить все поля. А вы вообще никакую точку памяти в поле `door_Info` не поставили и никакой адрес в `Next` тоже.

Comment: Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос нужно знать, что такое у вас правильно. То есть : напишите условие задачи.

Comment: Ну для начала я просто хочу внести в список и затем его вывести. Но у меня получается по 2 элемента должно быть (id и status из door) в каждом узле.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала пишете конструкторы для каждой структуры.

```
void door_init ( struct door * const doo , int const id , int const st ) {
  doo -> id = id ;
  doo -> status = st ;
}

void node_init ( struct node * const no , struct door * const doo ) {
  no -> door_Info = doo ;
  no -> Next = ( void * ) 0 ;
}
```

Затем нужно выделить память для **каждого** объекта и вызвать для **каждого** из них конструкторы. Сначала создаём **door** его записываем в новый **node**. Получается один **node** уже создали правильно :

```
struct door * doo = malloc(sizeof(struct door));
door_init ( doo , 1 , 0 ) ;
struct node * no = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
node_init ( no , doo ) ;
```

Дальше задача будет создавать список. В цикле вы должны постоянно создавать элементы списка и их добавлять к уже существующему.
Создаём указатели на голову списка и на конец.
Если список пустой, то новый **node** записываем как голову и хвост.
Если список не пустой, то последнему **node** подправляем указатель на следующий элемент свежим и меняем указатель на последний элемент им же.

```
struct node * no_head = 0;
struct node * no_last = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++ ) {
    struct door * doo = malloc(sizeof(struct door));
    door_init ( doo , 1 , 0 ) ;
    struct node * no = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node_init ( no , doo ) ;
    if ( ! no_last ) {
      no_head = no ;
      no_last = no ;
    } else {
      no_last -> Next = no ;
      no_last = no ;
    }
}
```

В результате получаете указатели на голову списка **no_head** и на хвост **no_last**.
*Удалением списка попробуйте заняться самостоятельно.*

Comment: Так почему бы не сделать функцию для выделения памяти под структуру, с инициализацией?)

Comment: @ori Объект может существовать статически/в стеке/в свободной памяти/в массиве статическом/массиве в стеке/массиве в свободном. `struct node n[12];node_init(&n[6],0);`

Comment: Ну тогда теряется смысл от связного списка... 2 функции, одна инициализация, другая выделение памяти, с параметрами инициализации, вызов от туда, и все :)

Comment: Списков может быть много, адресованных на одни и те же объекты. Например с разными функциями сортировки. Так-что одна функция для создания и того и другого имеет смысл только для одной единой структуры. @ori